# Highlighted a specific string within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-parsing, highlighting

I have a simple HTML page in jsFiddle that should open .txt log files:

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');

    node.innerText = text;
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};

var status = '<h2><br/><center>I want to change the colour of the >>> @ <<< symbol</center></h2>',
  newStatus = status.replace(/@/g, '<span class="atSign">@</span>');
console.log(newStatus);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = newStatus;
```

```css
.atSign {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>.TXT Log Parser</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <h2><input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'></h2>
</center>
<br/>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

Link to JSFiddle Project:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/baivong/60py489j/
```

As you can see in the example, I can read the output as text, and I can even do a little bit of JS and CSS to change the colour of a specific character in  specific string.

Since the content of the .txt log is not in my html or js, how do you suggest I highlight content in the #output  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onload` function, you need to replace the `text` with the formatted HTML.

Take care not to insert the uploaded text as string-replaced HTML alone; that will allow arbitrary scripts (and other things) to be executed. Instead, split the text by `@`s, and append a styled `span` after each segment (except the last).

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    
    const lines = text.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const div = output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      const textSplitAroundAt = line.split('@');
      textSplitAroundAt.forEach((text, i) => {
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        if (i === textSplitAroundAt.length - 1) return;
        const span = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
        span.textContent = '@';
        span.className = 'atSign';
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```css
.atSign {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>.TXT Log Parser</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <h2><input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'></h2>
</center>
<br/>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

Comment: Hi CertainPerformance,

That's amazing! And I can see what you did the OnLoad function. It works :)

One problem I've got is that the formatting has changed. Feel free to test text parser before the changes, and test it again after you have added the 'output.appendChild'.

Any idea whether this can keep the original formatting on the .txt file? (ie: inline / recognize line breaks)